# Add ListView as headerview to an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a simple app where I have an ExpandableListView. The app works fine uptil the ExpandableListView. However, the problem arises when I add another ListView as a headerview to the ExpandableListView.

```
ListView headerlv = new ListView(this);
    String[] newNames = {"Kung Fu Panda 3","Inception","Zootopia","Fantastic Beasts"};
    headerlv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.lblListItem,newNames));
    expListView.addHeaderView(headerlv);
```

In the above code expListView is the parent view to which the newly created ListView is attached. However, the ListView shows only one item. How can I tell the ListView to stretch and contain all list items. Need help here

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you insert your ListView code into the layout.xml?

Comment: Wouldn't that make a mess because there will be 2 scrollable views?

Comment: Sorry, I ask to post in your question your xml code. To understand what's happening in your List View.

Comment: You mean R.layout.list_item ?

Comment: No, the layout of the Activity. That contains your ListView.

Comment: Added. Please check and help me

Comment: show screenshots.......

Comment: I understand the problem now. It's because the height of list_item is 55dp and it only shows one list item. But I still don't know how to stretch it to show all items... Will add screenshots